# Convert lambda to delegate at runtime

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, runtime

I'm trying to bind a delegate with static methods of `Expression` class at runtime. First, the following two assignments work on compile time:

```
public delegate void Progress(State value);

public enum State
{
}

public void DoStuff(int value)
{
}

...

Action<State> action = (State a) => { DoStuff((int)a); };
Progress actionDelegate = (State a) => { DoStuff((int)a); }; //this is what I'm trying to achieve
```

I'm trying to bind Progress delegate by using `Expression` class like this:

```
public void CreateDelegate()
{
    var value = Expression.Variable(typeof(State), "a");
    var castedValue = Expression.Convert(value, typeof(int));
    var method = GetType().GetMethod("DoStuff");
    var call = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(this), method, castedValue);

    var lamda = Expression.Lambda(call, value);
    Progress compiled = (Progress)lamda.Compile(); //Invalid cast from Action<State> to Progress       
}
```

`Lambda.Compile` returns `Action<State>` but I need it to be `Progress` delegate. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var lamda = Expression.Lambda<Progress>(call, value);
Progress compiled = lamda.Compile();
```